# Private github respository authentication issues

Tags: git, authentication, github

I am using my work windows 10 pc. We have a private github repository. 99% times the authentication to the repo fails (be it pull/push, etc).

```
PS C:\Users\my_account> git pull
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com': git_handle
Password for 'https://git_handle@github.com':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/private.git/'
```

I have tried many things, e.g.

- authenticate with no Personal Access Tokens,
- setting up Personal Access Tokens,
- removing prior github credential stored in Web Credentials
- Used two different versions of git

  - the one provided by the company - v2.22
  - removing the above and installing the latest from the web (v2.32.0)

The bizarre thing is that once in a while it works and mostly it does not. Is there a way to debug (get more log or get to the lowest details of why authentication failed)?

Comment: What does git status say?

Comment: you need to provide more info on that

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by any chance? Or running crazy anti virus with interception certs?

Comment: @SamuelWahlberg  it status returns the following: `On branch branch_name; Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branch_name' by 1 commit.; (use "git push" to publish your local commits); nothing to commit, working tree clean'

Comment: @ahmedazhar05 what more information you would want. I provided all that I get by running git pull above.

Comment: @jessehouwing our company does have a firewall and we windows security.

Comment: @jessehouwing like, is remote repo linked to your local repo and if so how is it linked. check `git remote -v` and `git branch -ra`

Comment: you might need to set HEAD or URL or somthing like that